# Is it possible to have NERDTree open file in a selected window?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

Suppose I have 4 split windows with window number 1 the file explorer and window number 2-4 different file buffers. Can I have NERDTree open a new file in a selected window, say window number 4? I know in netrw I can do 4C<CR>, but I failed to find similar option in NERDTree.

Comment: Obligatory: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `o` command open the file in the previous window.

I would from the NERDTree window:

- Hit `4`<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`w` to visit window 4
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`p` to switch back to NERDTree
- Hit `o` to open the file

It would be possible to create a special mapping for that if needed.